# How can we download the chrome driver 117 from internet? The link https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ is downloading zip file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

If we download the zip file from the link, it does not have a chrome driver, it has chrome.exe file.
I am using selenium python. My chrome version is 117. I am using latest selenium version v4.6

I have used

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

I am getting the following error: **Exception has occurred: SessionNotCreatedException
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 115
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.134 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe**

If i work with chrome driver 115, it is showing the same, please help!

I want the chrome session to be created and run some selenium script. But I am facing issues with chrome and chrome driver mismatch.

Sol-1: Download chrome driver 117 version and use it, but I am unable to find the chromedriver.exe in the official link and the downloaded zip.

Sol-2: Downgrade my chrome version to 115 and use 115 chromedriver and run the files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the correct link for the chromedriver.

try to use one of the links under the red square, depending on your platform

[image]

after downloading the zip, unzip it and you will find the chromedriver.exe, i tried for the one of windows

[image]